# What does de if-Block mean

Tags: c++, if-statement, addition

What does the addition in the if block mean? What does the if-Question compare?

I have tried the code with integers, but it shows me the the if-block is every time true

```
if (f(a,751) + f(b, -751) -f(c, a))
```

.

Comment: You are using the expression `f(a,751) + f(b, -751) -f(c, a)` as the condition. Impossible to say what will happen without knowing what function `f` does and what variables `a`, `b`, and `c` are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What does the addition in the if block mean?

It means exactly the same as anywhere else and depends what type expression `f(a,751)` etc has. So your `if` statement is logically equal to:

```
auto tmp = f(a,751) + f(b, -751) -f(c, a);
if( tmp ) ...
```

this way it could be easier for you to understand that `+` does not have special meaning  inside `if`

> What does the if-Question compare?

C++ has special rules how certain types can be converted to type `bool` that `if` expects. For example for `int` any non zero value converts to `true` and `false` otherwise. Without knowing what `f()` returns it is impossible to say more.

You should understand that there is nothing special with `a < b` for example, it is just an expression that returns `bool`. `if` just evaluates what inside brackets and tries to convert it to `bool`. If it can it uses it, if it cannot you will get compilation error.

Answer (score 2):

In the code shown, the whole expression `f(a,751) + f(b, -751) - f(c, a)` is evaluated, and if it would return a value convertable to bool (for example, integer) the branch will be taken if the value is converted to `true`. For integers, it would mean if the value is non-0.

Absent definition of `f` function I can't elaborate further.

Answer (score 2):

The addition is just that, addition. Assuming f() returns an integer, the if statement simply is evaluating a condition that's an integer. In this case, any nonzero number will return true.